# Proving two space-time intervals are equivalent with matrix algebra

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry, linear-algebra

η=$ \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $

v=$ \begin{bmatrix}
ct\\
x\\
y\\
z 
\end{bmatrix}  $ v'=$ \begin{bmatrix}
ct'\\
x'\\
y'\\
z' 
\end{bmatrix}  $

The two events which are observing the same phenomenon are denoted by v and v'. These two phenomenon are related by the equation $v′= Λv$

Given that $s′= (v′)^Tηv′$ and that $s= (v)^Tηv$ demonstrate that $s=s'$.

I was wondering if it is at all possible to carry out the proof without using lorentz transformations, and only using matrix algebra and how I would go about it.

Comment: How did you define Lorentz transformations? As far as I know this is usually presented as the definition.

Comment: Yeah, this is the definition, but I was wondering whether it was possible to prove that s=s' using matrix algebra and the information provided, because I vaguely remember doing that a couple of years ago.

Comment: Well, since $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transformation if it leaves $s$ invariant, there's nothing to prove. Formally you would express this definition as $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transformation iff $\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda= \eta$. Using this definition and plugging it into $(v')^T \eta v'$ showing $s=s'$ should be easy, but it's a bit of a circular reasoning.

Comment: *The two events which are observing the same phenomenon are denoted by v and v'.* I wouldn't say "two events". Events are points of spacetime, and here you have just one point. Its coordinates are frame-dependent and you are concerned with relationship between those coordinates in different frames.